# How to get the first child value using dapper (typically querying count(*) as the only result)

Tags: c#, sql, orm, dapper

I want to implement some function like this:

```
public static string GetResult(string sql) {
    // TODO: 
    // result = connection.Query(....);
    // return result.FirstRow().FirstChild().ToString();
}
```

And call like this:

```
string myName = GetResult("SELECT userName from tb_Users WHERE ID = 1");
// or
int totalRows = Convert.ToInt32(GetResult("SELECT count(*) FROM tb_List"));
```

How can I implement TODO section using Dapper ?

Comment: It depends entirely on what you're telling `Dapper` the object type is. `First()` will give you the first row. If you tell `Dapper` the object type is `string`, you should be able to simply return `Query<string>(sql).First();`. Also - running `ToString()` on the result and then parsing it back into an typed value is asking for trouble.

Comment: @Rob helps me a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper has `ExecuteScalar[<T>]` which can be used if you are reading one column, one row, one grid. So:

```
var name = connection.ExecuteScalar<string>("select 'abc'");
int count = connection.ExecuteScalar<int>("select 123");
```

There is also `Query{First|Single}[OrDefault][<T>]` for all the usual "sort of one row, multiple columns" scenarios.

A word of caution on your API: anything that *only* accepts a string of sql (and no separate parameters) makes me very nervous that you are about to cause sql injection problems.

Comment: thank u for caution, my codes above are just sample to make you easy to read :P